# Need to get the PDF title from browser in Selenium Java

Tags: java, pdf, selenium-webdriver, pdfbox

Need to get the PDF title from browser in Selenium Java.

Able to get the content from the below code using PDFBox and FontBox. But unable to read the PDF title title. Could you please help.

public String readPDFInURL() throws EmptyFileException, IOException {

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // page with example pdf document

    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/theleader.pdf");

    URL url = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    InputStream is = url.openStream();

    BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    PDDocument document = null;

    try {

        document = PDDocument.load(fileToParse);

        String output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);

    } finally {

        if (document != null) {

            document.close();

        }

        fileToParse.close();

        is.close();

    }

    return output;

}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the PrintDocumentMetaData.java example and the ExtractMetadata.java examples in the source code download (yes there are two titles).

Comment: EmptyFileException is quite eloquent.